# Can't execute SQL Server 2014 setup for reinstall because it throws a blank error message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem when I try to execute SQL Server setup after uninstall previous installed.

I think I know the cause of the problem but at the same time I don't because I already installed SQL Server 2014 version I took from my friend but I had some problems and I had to delete it and reinstall it and when I try to reinstall throws this blank error message

[image]

Comment: It's strange that there's an .iso file in that folder.  Try mounting the ISO and running the installer from there.

Comment: I've got the iso file from a friend, i extract it to get the setup.

Comment: Then download and install the (free) SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: I think I know the cause of the problem but at the same time I don't 
because I already installed Sql Server 2014 version I took from my friend but I had some problems and I had to delete it and reinstall it 
and when I try to reinstall throws this blank error message

Comment: 70Kb for the installation file? That seems wrong.

Comment: It works with me correctly at the first time but when I desinstalled the sql server and ii want to reinstall it didnt work